# Why it's difficult for a stemmer to work on some non-regular words

Tags: nlp, nltk

This question may have more things to do with philosophy than with coding. The nltk provides both a tag package that marks each word of a sentence with a tagger, and a stem package that turn a word to its base form. I noted that the stemmer often fails to turn some non-regular words to its base form. For example, "It's" to "It is", "knew" to "know", "got" to "get", and so on. This is a bit surprising given the fact that the tagger can correctly tag "'s" as a verb in its right form ("VBZ"), and recognize the difference between "knew" ("VBD") and "know" ("VB"). Since we already know "knew" is a verb in its past tense, why it's difficult for a stemmer to correctly return its base form? It seems the best stemmer available is the snowball stemmer, though its performance is not satisfying.

Comment: because they are irregular. Best method i've seen is with a irregular verb table + a finite state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noted that the stemmer often fails to turn some non-regular words to its base form.

The stemmer is doing what it is designed to do: "Stemming usually refers to a crude heuristic process that chops off the ends of words in the hope of achieving this goal correctly most of the time, and often includes the removal of derivational affixes. Lemmatization usually refers to doing things properly with the use of a vocabulary and morphological analysis of words, normally aiming to remove inflectional endings only and to return the base or dictionary form of a word, which is known as the lemma." ([Source](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html))

If you want a linguistically appropriate base form, use a lemmatizer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, any lemmatizer to recommend?

Comment: @starforever: This is a popular toolset: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml